# Copy Contents From Folder Using Wildcard On The Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, wildcard

I have a directory which contains CSV files needing to be moved to another directory:

```
C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\Testing\report-20180819040000-20180826040000-4
```

We receive a new file weekly where the dates in the directory name will be updated. I want to create a batch file to copy this data using a wildcard on `report*` but I am running into some issues.

The wildcard appears to work without any issues when I first navigate to:

```
C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\Testing\
```

then use:

```
dir report*
```

It also works fine when I navigate to:

```
C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\Testing\
```

then run

```
copy * C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\Testing\Destination
```

My goal is to be able to run something simple in my batch file like the below:

```
copy C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\Testing\report* C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\Testing\Destination
```

Whenever I try running the above, I receive the following error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.
>           0 file(s) copied.`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `Copy` is a command for copying files, but I don't see any `.csv` files mentioned in any of your code snippets. Can you please clarify whether `report-20180819040000-20180826040000-4` is the name of a directory or the name of a file with the `.csv` extension missing.

Comment: `report-20180819040000-20180826040000-4` is the name of the directory tht contains the `.csv` files.

Comment: Two things, 1. As stated, `Copy` copies files and your providing it with a directory. 2. Your question states 'move' but your copying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `For /D` with a wildcards for your directory name, then you can use `Copy` with a wildcard too!

From the Command Prompt:

```dos
For /D %A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\Testing\report-*-*-*") Do @Copy "%A\*.csv" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Testing\Destination">Nul 2>&1
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /D %%A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\Testing\report-*-*-*") Do @Copy "%%A\*.csv" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Testing\Destination">Nul 2>&1
```

Alternatively you could do it directly at the Powershell Prompt:

```ps1
Cp "$($Env:UserProfile)\Desktop\Testing\report-*-*-*\*.csv" "$($Env:UserProfile)\Desktop\Testing\Destination"
```

Comment: This is perfect. Can I then use this same (similar) script to remove this folder once the copy is complete?

Comment: Disregard. I got it using a similar script. Thanks!